# Using an old 2 way switch in 3 way setup

Tags: relay, lighting

i'm not an expert in electronics and i'm keen to get some guidance on the below...

I have an old vintage 1-way (On\Off) light switch I would like to use as a 2-way switch to control a light from two locations (the other light switch is a modern 2-way (COM, L1, L2)).

I am very keen to use this old 1-way switch, hence the reason to not just replace it with a modern 2-way switch (it looks nice!).

My current thoughts are to use a Relay and wire up COM, NO, NC as you would for a 2-way switch and use the 1-way switch to activate \ deactivate this Relay, but I am not sure how best to do this?

Keen to get feedback on how this may be possible or any better solutions that could allow me to use this 1-way switch in such a setup?

Many thanks!

Comment: You're on the right track to use a single-pole-double-throw (SPDT) relay to substitute for a SPDT switch. The main challenge will be finding a suitably approved (UL, etc) relay with contacts that can carry the lighting current, and a box to house it. Unfortunately, in one of the switch positions, the relay coil will always be drawing current, so you have to take heating into account. You could consider converting to a wireless remote, but it will introduce other hassles.

Comment: You can use a relay as you've planned to use as a 2-way switch, just use some basic relay board, with a basic driver circuit. You can also use a microcontroller for advanced use and adding gestures. But using your switch in this way, a power supply needs to run 24hrs, so a reliable power supply is needed.

Comment: How to best do it depends on where you live and who is legally allowed in your jurisdiction to wire mains voltage installations.

Comment: Many thanks for the super fast replies - my first post on this site :)
Very valid points, im in Poland and have wired up other 230v Relays for automation via a Pi. I can see that I could have a simple microcontroller to control the relay but thought this would be overkill and was hoping there may be a better way. 

Justme - yep and agree, as of now I want to get an idea if this is possible.

Comment: Relay is a good option. If you want to minimise power loss you could use a latching relay but that adds complexity and the coil power is liable to be low.